# Open visio using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, office365, win32com

I've a weird problem. I have coded a little python script to test if my idea would work (no worries, it's just for fun). I am trying to simply open visio, place a couple of objects and close it.

```
#Get visio application
import win32com.client as win32
visio = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Visio.Application')
visio.Visible = True
```

And it worked, so I've left it as it is for this week and when I tested it again it gave me an error which didn't occur last time, and closed the application.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lars\OneDrive - HAN\School LJ 3\Stage\Stageopdrachten\Opdracht interactive netwerktekening\Programma\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    visio = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Visio.Application')
  File "C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 524, in EnsureDispatch
    disp = win32com.client.Dispatch(prog_id)
  File "C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 96, in Dispatch       
    return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, userName, resultCLSID, typeinfo, clsctx=clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 37, in __WrapDispatch
    klass = gencache.GetClassForCLSID(resultCLSID)
  File "C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 180, in GetClassForCLSID
    mod = GetModuleForCLSID(clsid)
  File "C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 223, in GetModuleForCLSID
    mod = GetModuleForTypelib(typelibCLSID, lcid, major, minor)
  File "C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 263, in GetModuleForTypelib
    AddModuleToCache(typelibCLSID, lcid, major, minor)
  File "C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 559, in AddModuleToCache
    SetTypelibForAllClsids(mod.CLSIDToClassMap)
AttributeError: module 'win32com.gen_py.00021A98-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x4x16' has no attribute 'CLSIDToClassMap'
```

Does anybody know what happened, or what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to reverse an update that happened in the meantime. I've been looking if the win32com has been updated. Yet nothing did solve it.

I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awnser to this question has been posted here:
[Why am I suddenly getting a no attribute 'CLSIDToPackageMap' error with win32com.client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267002/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-no-attribute-clsidtopackagemap-error-with-win32com)

In short the problem can be solved by deleting the gen_py folder found in the temp folder. You can find the temp folder by searching for %temp% or go to c:\users<username>\appdata\local\temp (make sure to show hidden files).

Hope I was able to help.